# Detect the writing system of a string in Python

Tags: python, unicode

Is there an easy way to detect what writing system(s) is used by a string in Python 3?

For example:

- "Yamamoto" → Latin alphabet
- "山本" → Kanji
- "やまもと" → Hiragana
- "Ямамото" → Cyrillic
  etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heres a one liner (Python 3.X)-

```
import unicodedata
langname = lambda x : unicodedata.name(x[0]).split(' ')[0]
```

Output -

```
>>> langname('Yamamoto')
'LATIN'

>>> langname('やまもと')
'HIRAGANA'
```

Answer (score 4):

A quick google search dropped this: [alphabet-detection](https://github.com/EliFinkelshteyn/alphabet-detector).

You can use it as the documentation states:

```
>>> from alphabet_detector import AlphabetDetector
>>> ad = AlphabetDetector()
>>> ad.detect_alphabet(u'Cyrillic and кириллический')
{'CYRILLIC', 'LATIN'}
```

Comment: This library in-fact uses the same method as in my answer! Point being you don't need to install just another library to do such a trivial task :)

Comment: @hashcode55 it does indeed. Didn't have a look in depth, and it seems to be a single *simple* module.

Comment: Yeah and 86 stars too haha.